# умножение NSString на NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

Доброе время суток! Пытаюсь умножить два NSString между собой, подскажите, пожалуйста , как это сделать?!

```
    - (IBAction)plus:(id)sender {
    w = m * y;
    [_coli setText:w];}
```

Выдает:  invalid operands to binary expression (NSString and NSString).
Нашел пару вариантов:

```
    NSString *concat = [TextField1.text stringByAppendingString:TextField2.text];
    NSString *concat = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@%@", TextField1.text, TextField2.text];
```

Но они просто выводят два значения рядом, например надо умножить 500 на 2, получается 5002.

Comment: а что вы хотите чтоб получалось при умножении "500" и "2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что вы хотите умножить числа, которые хранятся в строковых переменных

```
NSString *string1 = @"500";
NSString *string2 = @"2";

NSString *stringResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [string1 integerValue] * [string2 integerValue]];
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!